# Ms's to date format?

Tags: bash

Not sure how to describe this but want to simplify this ...

```
declare -i seconds=0
seconds=$(mediainfo --Inform="General;%Duration%" "$1")/1000
eval "echo $(date -ud "@$seconds" +'%l:%M')"
```

I couldn't divide the return ms by 1000 without declaring it first, but can I somehow get the 2 first lines all into "@$seconds" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn’t show the whole script, but I assume you don’t really need `eval` and `echo` in the last line. You can use a [`bash` Arithmetic Expression](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) `$((…))` as follows:

```
date -ud "@$(($(mediainfo --Inform="General;%Duration%" "$1")/1000))" +%l:%M
```

Because `%l` is “hour, space padded ( 1..12)” `%l:%M` gives a wrong output, for a movie with `00:56:40` it shows `12:56`. Maybe you want something different, but I’ve never seen 12-hour format used on a duration – if displaying the file’s duration in HH:MM format with space-padded hours is what you want `+%_H:%M` does the trick:

```
$ date -ud@"$(($(mediainfo --Inform="General;%Duration%" /path/to/file)/1000))" +%_H:%M
 0:56
```

#### Further reading

- [bash hackers wiki article on Arithmetic Expressions](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr)
- [`man bash`/ARITHMETIC EVALUATION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#arithmetic%20evaluation)

Comment: Thanks, thought the eval said echo.